# Enabling fog in react-three/drei shaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am trying to enable fog in my custom shader. I would assume that shaderMaterial automatically passes down global fog variables but couldn't find any documentation. I did look at the posts for plain Three.js but couldn't manage to map the solutions to the react-three/drei shaderMaterial. Any help would be greatly appreciated.